# A MYSQL query limited to one enum type excluding others

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a query.

My table structure looks like so:

```
submitted_name   type             user_submitted_id   submitted_id
Red              manager          1                       10
Red              sales            1                       11
Red              IT               1                       12
Green            IT               2                       13
Green            sales            2                       14
Blue             sales            3                       15
Yellow           sales            4                       16
Aqua Blue        manager          1                       17
Lime Green       manager          1                       18
Lime Green       sales            1                       19
```

How would I write my query which would show me only the submitted_names which only have the type "sales" and no other types. Type is an `enum` data type. Names are not unique.

submitted_name is not an indexed column and this database has about 15 million rows.

So given this test data, the result should be

```
`blue | sales | 2`
'Yellow | sales | 4'
```

I've tried doing some distincts and group by's/havings but keep drawing a blank on how exactly to structure this. I know this isn't the most complicated question, but it's been awhile since I've done SQL queries and couldn't figure out the best approach to "googling" for this.

Comment: `WHERE type = 'sales'`?

Comment: Hope i understood the question right... If the sample output only includes "blue", then that is probably because "blue" doesnt have other types

Comment: type = 'sales' doesn't exclude properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.* FROM my_table t1
   LEFT JOIN my_table t2
      ON t1.submitted_name = t2.submitted_name AND t1.type != t2.type
   WHERE t1.type='sales' AND t2.type IS NULL
```

This finds all records in `my_table` which have `type=sales`, and no record with same `submitted_name` exist having a different `type`.

**EDIT:** Alternative approach:

```
SELECT submitted_name,GROUP_CONCAT(`type`) AS `type`,GROUP_CONCAT(`id`) AS `id`
FROM my_table
GROUP BY submitted_name
HAVING `type`='sales'
```

What this does is - take all records and group them by `submitted_name`, but then filter them to only the ones having a single type "sales".

I can't promise you will have a huge performance boost given your table size (or even have any boost at all, since there will be a full-scan on your 12M records table anyway), but at least there will not be a join.

**EDIT2:** Given the new information, it is definitely a good idea to use an indexed column (`user_submitted_id`) instead of `submitted_name` for joins/group by, in both scenarios.

The first query will look like this:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM my_table t1
   LEFT JOIN my_table t2
      ON t1.user_submitted_id = t2.user_submitted_id AND t1.type != t2.type
   WHERE t1.type='sales' AND t2.type IS NULL
```

**NB**: Note that it is a good idea to specify the exact columns in this query instead of `t.*`, this will decrease memory consumption by the result set, and may result in performance gain.

And the second query will look like this:

```
SELECT submitted_name,GROUP_CONCAT(`type`) AS `type`,GROUP_CONCAT(`id`) AS `id`
FROM my_table
GROUP BY user_submitted_id
HAVING `type`='sales'
```

Comment: so I needed to join the table onto itself?

Comment: This is the correct answer. The join selects all submitted names that are equal, while they have different types. If type is NULL in that case, it only has one type being 'sales'.

Comment: I think I'm on minute ten of this query running. ha

Comment: @JackMarchetti how many records are there in the table? And what are the indexes?

Comment: 12 million. The columns I'm joining on are not indexed unfortunately.

Comment: Can you add a `KEY(type,submitted_name)`? Cause running a 12M x 12M join is seriously resource hungry in any case, and if you make mysql do this without indexes - that results in full scan of the whole thing...

Comment: I can't add an index, no.

Comment: Added alternative (using `HAVING` clause). Check both and see which one gives you better performance

Comment: I updated the question with some more context. The ID is actually a user_id which is indexed. I'm wondering if that would be a better way of identifying the rows?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49498/discussion-between-jack-marchetti-and-poncha)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * 
    from table_name
    where  submitted_name in (select distinct(submitted_name)  from table_name
        minus
        select distinct(submitted_name) from table_name where type<>sales)
```

Comment: Submitted names aren't unique so you could have 500,000 submitted_names named "blue". Distinct would eliminate all of those right?

Comment: @jack Marchetti Yes it will remove the non unique one will only return the names and then exclude the names with type sales and finally return the required set give a try to this solution